# Menu field is not closing, when clicked on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have one question with my code.

I have created this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/b6rhxaxd/10/)** from jsfiddle.net

When you click the red div then the menu will opening but if you click the menu items the menu area will not closing.

What do i need to close the menu area when clicked the menu?

```
<div class="p_change" tabindex="0" id="1">
  <div class="pr_icon"><div class="icon-kr icon-globe"></div>CLICK</div>
   <div class="pr_type">
     <div class="type_s change_pri md-ripple" data-id="0"><div class="icon-pr icon-globe"></div>1</div>
     <div class="type_s change_pri md-ripple" data-id="1"><div class="icon-pr icon-contacs"></div>2</div>
     <div class="type_s change_pri md-ripple" data-id="2"><div class="icon-pr icon-lock-1"></div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="p_change" tabindex="0" id="2">
  <div class="pr_icon"><div class="icon-kr icon-globe"></div>CLICK</div>
   <div class="pr_type">
     <div class="type_s change_pri md-ripple" data-id="0"><div class="icon-pr icon-globe"></div>1</div>
     <div class="type_s change_pri md-ripple" data-id="1"><div class="icon-pr icon-contacs"></div>2</div>
     <div class="type_s change_pri md-ripple" data-id="2"><div class="icon-pr icon-lock-1"></div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.pr_icon').on('click',function(e){
    // Change Post Privacy 
    $('.change_pri').on('click',function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
      var dataid = $(this).attr('data-id');
      var id = $(this).closest('.p_change').attr('id');
      var class_name = $(this).find(".icon-pr").attr("class");
      class_name = class_name.replace(/icon\-pr\s+/gi, "");
      $(this).closest(".p_change").find(".icon-kr").removeClass().addClass("icon-kr " + class_name);
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "change_id.php",
           data: { dataid : dataid, id: id }
           }).success(function(html){
            if (html.trim() === "1") {
               // Do Something
             } else {
             // Do something
             }
           });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `document.ready` function's braces `});`

And you have to add this line on the `onclick` function of `.change_pri`

```
$('.change_pri').on('click',function(event){
 $(this).closest('.pr_type').children().hide();
```

Check out the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6rhxaxd/11/)

**EDIT:**

If you want to again show them, use two different classes to identify them separately.
In your example I have used classes `.first_click_content` and `.second_click_content`

And one more thing, you do not have to write an `onclick` function of `.change_pri` inside `.pr_icon`. You can separate them out.

Check out the updated **[Newly Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6rhxaxd/13/)**

**New EDIT based on your question in comment**

You just have to remove the `padding` and increase the `margin-top`

Check out the **[New Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/b6rhxaxd/17/)**

Comment: then menu will not opening again ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but some question. What is the `.second_click_content `? Why i am asking this if i have so many menu in one page then what can id do on that time like this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/b6rhxaxd/14/)

Comment: You have to dynamically generate class names by looping thorugh the html using `jQuery's each()` function only if you do not know how many click buttons will be there, else it is alright to place it statically.

Comment: Ok one more question if i click the menu then the menu hiding but `.pr_type` staying on there. What should i do for it to hide also `.pr_type` ?

Comment: This is my first question and you give me best help. Thank you so Much.